# Cannot use vggface-keras in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use the keras-vggface library from https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface to train a CNN. I have installed tensorflow 2.0.0-rc1, keras 2.3.1, cuda 10.1, cudnn 7.6.5 and the driver's version is 418, the problem is that when i try to use the vggface model, as a convolutional base, i get an error, here is the code and the error

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace 
conv_base = VGGFace(model='vgg16', include_top=False)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(800, activation='softmax'))
```

Error!

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-f6b5cad8f44b> in <module>
          1 #arquitectura
          2 model = models.Sequential()
    ----> 3 model.add(conv_base)
          4 model.add(layers.Flatten())
          5 model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

~/anaconda3/envs/vggface/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
        455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
        456     try:
    --> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        458     finally:
        459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/anaconda3/envs/vggface/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
        156       raise TypeError('The added layer must be '
        157                       'an instance of class Layer. '
    --> 158                       'Found: ' + str(layer))
        159 
        160     tf_utils.assert_no_legacy_layers([layer])

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f0bf03db210>
```

I hope you can tell me why i get this error and how to solve it, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is incompatibility between `keras` and `tf.keras`. The library you are using (vggface-keras), uses `keras`, while your code uses `tf.keras`. This won't work.

The only possible solutions is you to use `keras` for your whole pipeline, or for you to modify the `vggface-keras` library to use `tf.keras`, including modifying all imports and fixing any bugs that appear.

Comment: thanks for the awnser im doing that stuff and working on it, if i found something that i can't handle, i will edit up there, else i will share my stuff thanks for now

Answer (score 1):

here is a page, where you can download the .h5 file with the weights of the vggface model, so we can use it to train in tensorflow with higher versions than 1.15

https://sefiks.com/2018/09/03/face-recognition-with-facenet-in-keras/

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to use vggface in Tensorflow 2 so created [this fork of keras-vggface](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/vggface). You should be able to use `python setup.py install` to install it (after cloning).

Answer (score -1):

VGG-Face is wrapped in deepface framework for python. Just pass VGG-Face string to model name variable.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
obj = DeepFace.verify([
      ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"],
      ["img1.jpg", "img3.jpg"],
      ["img1.jpg", "img4.jpg"],
   ]
   , model_name = "VGG-Face")
print(obj)
```

This block will check img1 among img2, img3, img4.

Comment: sorry, but this works to retrain a neural net? can i use all the layers except the last 3, like w/ tensorflow and keras?

Comment: this builds a tensorflow / keras model up in the background. you don't need to retrain it but if you can still retrain it if you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the stuff here is that i have 20k diferent persons w/ about 300 pics of them, im trying to clasify them in a ip cam stream, i dont know if making the deepface.verify would be the wright aproach, what do you think?

Comment: large scale face recognition is handled with find function in deepface. It finds vector representations of faces in your db once - (20k person x 300 picture). Then, applying face recogntinion will be handled in just seconds. read me documentation of the repo explains it deeply.